# Generate unseen numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, binary

Let us say a substring is any continuous section of an original string.  For example `cat` is a substring of `concatenate`.  We will say that a *proper* substring is a substring that is not equal to the original string.  For example `concatenate` is a substring of `concatenate` but not a proper substring. (single character strings have no proper substrings)

We will now define a sequence using these terms.  The **n**th term in this sequence will be the smallest number such that there is a proper substring of its binary representation that is not a substring of any earlier term in the sequence.  The first term is `10`.

As an exercise lets generate the first 5 terms.  I will work in binary to make things easier.

The first term is `10`. Since `11`, the next smallest number, has only one proper substring, `1` which is also a substring of `10`, `11` is not in the sequence.  `100` however does contain the proper substring `00` which is not a substring of `10` so `100` is our next term.  Next is `101` which contains the unique proper substring `01` adding it to the sequence, then `110` contains the proper substring `11` which is new adding it to the sequence.

Now we have

```
10, 100, 101, 110
```

`111` is up next but it contains only the substrings `1` and `11` making it not a term.  `1000` however contains `000` adding it to the sequence.

Here are the first couple terms in decimal

```
2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 50, 54, 56, 58
```

### Task

Either

- Take **n** as input and generate the **n**th term in this sequence (either 0 or 1 indexed)
- Continuously output terms of the sequence

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers are scored in bytes with less bytes being better.

Comment: Is the output supposed to be in decimal or binary? Or either?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I think it's supposed to be integers.

Comment: Could add the 100th term (or any  other large `n`) ?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork  You should output in any standard allowed format.

Comment: @Rod Is 36 large enough? `a(36)` is 47 (1 indexed).

Comment: @WheatWizard `a(100)` is `144` (0 indexed)

Comment: @Rod Looks like I have a bug.  I've deleted all entries afterwards until I can fix the bug.

Comment: is empty string a valid sub string of any string? Is empty string a valid proper sub string to any non-empty string?

Comment: @tsh Yes to both.  However it doesn't matter because it will never be unique.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>88</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> 75 bytes

<sup>-6 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard</sup>
<sup>-2 bytes thanks to RootTwo</sup>
<sup>-3 bytes thanks to notjagan</sup>

```python
s={0}
n=1
while 1:n+=1;b=f"{n:b}";p={b[1:],b[:-1]};s|=p-s and{b,print(n)}|p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAu68IT0UKLd2UfYl4aKkoiG3JIMJ8u83Ie28nj7UmzENRjKCebT@WBhz3CJ5w1ZkdFe0FMwVw0VBwFmLx6UOxqZl4zmTk2vluuSuf1PoD)

Comment: [Porting to python 3 saves 4 bytes if you want](https://tio.run/##DcoxCsMwDADA3a/wmNjxoHST0UuEFkFLDEUVdaCUkLc7ufn8v28fe4zRiSUYQfht7f2MgCFaJqhK2myymVeU6sTKgLIoYwGRENvrSH6WI/UT/dtsv2vtmTyzyhgX "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [Actually 7](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDADAva8oToo6RLeUvKR0CSgWJAYriNS@vXrz6XNth8y1JspNU4wQmHuL@2IBjZWewDFxlFY6P2FwSpk9YBjY4wihGBtXq2NCPaNc/3LpJX0zl1o/ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard ninja'd

Comment: In Python 3.6, you can save 2 more by replacing `bin(n)[2:]` with `f"{n:b}"`.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAu68IT0UKLd2UfYl4aKkoiG3JIMJ8u83Ie28nj7UmzENRjKCebT@WBhz3CJ5w1ZkdFe0FMwVw0VBwFmLx6UOxqZl4zmTk2vluuSuf1PoD) with some really weird changes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
BẆṖ
ṄÇ;ð⁹Çḟ¥?⁹⁸‘¤ß
2ç⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p4a62hzuncT3c2XK43frwhkeNOw@3P9wx/9BSeyDzUeOORw0zDi05PJ/L6PByIO//fwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <strike>116</strike> 110 bytes

```
x={};f=Subsequences[#~IntegerDigits~2]&;Do[MemberQ[Most@f@n,s_/;FreeQ[f/@x,s,2]]&&x~AppendTo~Echo@n,{n,2,∞}]
```

Infinitely outputs terms of the sequence.

## Explanation

```
x={};
```

`x` is the list of terms of the sequence so far.

```
f=Subsequences[#~IntegerDigits~2]&
```

`f` is a `Function` which takes an integer and returns all `Subsequences` of its base `2` representation (including the empty list `{}` and the full list of `IntegerDigits` itself).

```
Do[...,{n,2,∞}]
```

Evaluate `...` for value of `n` from `2` to `∞`.

```
...&&x~AppendTo~Echo@n
```

If `...` is `False`, then the second argument to `And` (`&&`) is never evaluated. If `...` is `True`, then `Echo@n` prints and returns `n`, which we then `AppendTo` the list `x`.

```
MemberQ[Most@f@n,s_/;FreeQ[f/@x,s,2]]
```

We want to check that some proper substring of `n` is not a substring of any previous term in the sequence. `Most@f@n` is the list of proper substrings of `n`, we then check whether there are any substrings `s_` which is a `MemberQ` of that list such that the list `f/@x` of lists of substrings of previous terms of the sequence is `FreeQ` of `s` at level `2`.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>109</s> 94 bytes

```
s={};Do[!SubsetQ[s,(t=Subsequences@IntegerDigits[i,2])[[2;;-2]]]&&(s=s~Join~t;Echo@i),{i,∞}]
```

Continuously output terms of the sequence

*Special thanx to **@ngenisis** for -15 bytes*

## Mathematica, 123 bytes

```
(s=r={};For[i=2,i<2#,i++,If[!ContainsAll[s,(t=Subsequences@IntegerDigits[i,2])[[2;;-2]]],s=s~Join~t;r~AppendTo~i]];r[[#]])&
```

Take n as input and generate the nth term in this sequence (1 indexed)

**input**

> [1000]

**output**

> 1342

Comment: Good idea to keep track of the substrings that have appeared so far! I spy at least`15` bytes that can go: `SubsetQ` is shorter than and equivalent to `ContainsAll`, you can use `And` instead of `If`, the `Union` is unnecessary, and `Do` is almost always shorter than `For`: `s={};Do[!SubsetQ[s,(t=Subsequences@IntegerDigits[i,2])[[2;;-2]]]&&(s=s~Join~t;Echo@i),{i,∞}]`

Comment: `3` more bytes by using `Most`: `s={};Do[!SubsetQ[s,Most[t=Subsequences@IntegerDigits[i,2]]]&&(s=s~Join~t;Echo@i),{i,2,∞}]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
u+G
fP-Fm.:.Bd)+TG1Y
```

This prints the sequence infinitely. It can only be used offline as a consequence.

Explanation (The space is a newline):

```
u+G fP-Fm.:.Bd)+TG1Y
u                  Y    Apply the following function to the previous output
                        until it stops changing (or forever, in this case),
                        starting with the empty list
    f             1     Find the first positive integer where
               +TG      The integer prepended to the current list
        m               Map to
           .Bd          Convert to binary
         .:   )         Form all subsequences
      -F                Fold the filter-out function over the list
                        This iteratively removes all subsequences already seen
                        from the candidate
     P                  Remove the last subsequence which is the whole number.
   (newline)            Print that first integer
 +G                     Prepend that first integer to the list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
.V2I-=ZP.:jb2)Yb=+YZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/MyFPXNipAzyoryUgzMslWOzLq/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell,  172 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
b 0=""
b n=b(n`div`2)++(show$n`mod`2)
s=nub.(tails=<<).inits
p x=s x\\[x]
n(_,l)x|(p.b)x\\l/=[]=(x,l++(s.b)x)|1<2=(0,l)
filter(>1)$fst<$>scanl n(1,[])[1..]
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##FYzBboMwEETv/opVxGGtIBci9cbm1GP/gKBiGlBWMQvCm9SH/Dt1TvPmaTQ3H@9jCPvO87psCl9evfvmqGaAig6HHEIDSn/lZ3@yxyPG2/JXSD8v19xNJHkMDtVziNQ01rGwRrNCogjpcmlTZwR/ymDTC1c32OzCB7UdYSrD@@7t7KtuToRVnpmJJg46bniubTFFbYpz/PUSQLAu2862tXPdPnsWIFg3FoUC1N9H@KwyTfs/)

#### Explanation

The code generates the sequence continuously.

- `b` returns the binary representation of an `Int` as a `String`
- `s` returns all the substrings of a string
- `p` returns all the proper substrings of a string
- `n` is a function that is applied iteratively and returns a tuple containing:

  - the current element, if it is a member of the sequence, otherwise 0
  - a list of all substrings to check against for all following numbers
- finally, `scanl` is used to call `n` over and over again and its output is filtered to only contain elements greater than 1

Here's a slightly more readable version, before golfing:

```haskell
import Data.List

binary :: Int -> String
binary 0=""
binary n|(d,r)<-divMod n 2=binary d++["01"!!r]

substrings :: String -> [String]
substrings xs = nub$inits xs>>=tails

properSubstrings :: String -> [String]
properSubstrings xs = substrings xs\\[xs]

sb  = substrings.binary
psb = properSubstrings.binary

g = scanl step (1,[]) [1..]
  where step (_,l) x | psb x \\ l /= [] = (x,l++sb x)
                     | otherwise        = (0,l)

f=filter(>1)$fst<$>g
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 57 bytes

```
for(x=1;;x++)/^10|10(00)*$/.test(x.toString(2))&&alert(x)
```

```js
alert=x=>{if(x>100)throw 'Let we stop here.';document.write(x+'<br/>');};

for(x=1;;x++)/^10|10(00)*$/.test(x.toString(2))&&alert(x)
```

Let we write the given number *n* in binary form, then:

- If the number is starts with `10`, *n* must in the sequence:

  - remove the first `1` in it, the remaining binary string must not be seen, since *n* is the smallest number which may contain such string
- If the number is starts with `11`:

  - By removing the first `1` in it, the remaining binary string (let we donate it as `1x` must be seen since:

    - number `1x` is in the sequence, or
    - number `1x0` is in the sequence, since it contain unique sub string `1x`
  - If it is odd (ends with 1), it must not in the sequence, since:

    - (*n* - 1) / 2 in the sequence, or
    - (*n* - 1) in the sequence, since it contain unique sub string (*n* - 1) / 2
  - If it is even (ends with 0), it is in the sequence iff *n* / 2 is not in the sequence

    - with the same idea, *n* / 2 is *not* in the sequence iff *n* / 2 is odd, or n / 4 is in the sequence

Conclusion:

the binary form of the number starts with `10` or ends with `1` followed by odd number of `0`. Or describe in regex: x match `/^10|10(00)*$/`.